# Determine the length of a string in MIPS32

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm trying to determine the length of an input string using buffer and memory allocation. So lets say I allocate some memory and read a string and store it into the buffer. Then how can I figure out how long the string is?

Comment: What language? ASM/C/C++?

Comment: I apologize, I thought I'd already mentioned its supposed to be MIPS32.

Comment: MIPS32 = the CPU architecture, not the language, I guess you mean MIPS32 assembler then.

Comment: I apologize, I meant assembly

Answer (score 3):

Count from the beginning until you find a null character (0).

Something like:

```
la $t0 string

loop:
    lb   $t1 0($t0)
    beq  $t1 $zero end

    addi $t0 $t0 1
    j loop

end:

la $t1 string
sub $t3 $t0 $t1 #$t3 now contains the length of the string
```

Comment: Makes sense until you subtracted. Doesnt t0 already contain the length of the string? The moment you find a null character, $t0 stops increasing. So $t0 now contains the length of the string right? Then why do we need to subtract $t0 from $t1?

Comment: @SlyCooper I actually got that backwards. I'll edit it to say sub $t3 $t0 $t1. But the subtraction still is neccessary because these are addresses, not offsets